# How do I configure JSF url mappings without file extensions?

Tags: java, url, jsf, jakarta-ee, url-rewriting

Most tutorials propose a default JSF configuration similar to the following web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

With this configuration the corresponding *.xhtml files in my webapp are only found by the Faces Servlet if the corresponding URLs ends with the file extension .jsf (e.g. http://localhost/welcome.jsf). Is it possible to configure web.xml so URLs that do not end with .jsf are also processed as JSF pages using the same *.xhtml files?

In other words I would like to have URLs that do not depend on the server side implementation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use Filter to hide this extension and make your URL SEO friendly. One such implementation of Filter is [PrettyFaces](https://www.ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/).

For example: 
If you need `http://host:port/yourapp/login` to resolve with your `login.xhtml` then in pretty filter configure following way

```
<url-mapping id="login">
    <pattern> /login </pattern>
    <view-id> /legacy/user/login.jsf </view-id>
</url-mapping>
```

Have a look at [two min video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1kicjmLsN3w&feature=player_embedded) tutorial

Answer (score 3):

you can create url mapping like this 
create faces-config.xml file in WEB-INF folder

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
              version="1.2">

   <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/jsf/demoapp</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>demoapp</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/demoapp.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
   </navigation-rule>


</faces-config>
```

in web.xml you have to do 2 entries

```html
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jsfServlets</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

```html
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsfServlets</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/jsf/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Good to know, but only works for jsf right? It wouldn't work for other servlets.