# JSF 2 can't find my xhml files

Tags: java, jsf-2, view, web.xml

I have a web jsf project, with, inside my Web Pages directory:

```
/WEB-INF  
/faces  
/res  
index.jsp
```

My faces dir got the files all.xhtml and login.xhtml.

My web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/faces/login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

But when I run my project, JSF can't find any of my xhtml files. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7914802/527718), you have to define the mapping like this:

```
 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

or like that:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

#### see also:

- [How do I configure JSF url mappings without file extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860004/how-do-i-configure-jsf-url-mappings-without-file-extensions)
- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why)